# Characteristic function of stochastic process at a random time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a brownian motion $W = (W_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}}$ and a exponential distribution $T$ with rate $c$. What I want to compute is the mean and characteristic function of a random variable $W_{T}$ where $W_T(w) = W_{T(w)}(w)$ . A book says that by completing the characteristic function, we would know that $W_T$ has the same distribution as $Z_1 - Z_2$ where $Z_i$ are independent exponentially distributed random variable with rate $\sqrt{2c}$.

The question is deriven from the famous probability book from Erhan Cinlar, Probability and stochastics, where he discuss about the particle systems with birth and death (page 268~). I think the question is interesting itself, and I want to know the technique how to show such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $W$ and $T$ shall be independent. Let me first state some facts from Wikipedia, which you can also figure out as excercise.

- For $Z$ exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$ we have $\Bbb E [e^{isZ}] = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - i s} $, $s\in\Bbb R$
- For $X$ normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $v$ we have $\Bbb E [e^{isX}] = e^{i\mu s - \frac 1 2 v s^2}$, $s\in\Bbb R$

Therefore we have
$$\Bbb E[e^{isW_T}] = \int_0^\infty \Bbb E[e^{isW_t}] c e^{-ct}dt = \int_0^\infty e^{\frac 1 2 t s^2 } ce^{-ct} dt = \frac{c}{c + \frac 12 s^2} = \frac{2c}{2c+s^2}.$$

For $Z_1,Z_2$ independently exponentially distributed with rate $\sqrt{2c}$ holds
$$\Bbb E [e^{is (Z_1 - Z_2)}] = \Bbb E[e^{isZ_1}]\Bbb E [e^{i (-s)Z_2}] = \frac{\sqrt{2c}}{\sqrt{2c} - is} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2c}}{\sqrt{2c} + is}= \frac{2c}{2c + s^2} $$